# Из-за подключения jquery перестаёт работать плагин с fl.ru

Tags: html, css, jquery, плагин, search

Вот пример
 [jsfiddle.net/4ohx07ez/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/4ohx07ez/1/)

Взял с fl.ru плагин поиска по городам и странам

Просто скопировал необходимый js и css. Подключил их

Как только подключаю сторонний jquery (до или после кода плагина, не имеет значения) плагин перестаёт работать.

Что можно сделать, чтоб, как бы включать этот код независимо от jquqry? Чтоб они не видели друг друга. Или какой вообще выход из сутации посоветуете?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" slick-uniqueid="1">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link type="text/css" href="https://st.fl.ru/wdstatic/0f91224ad2a1ac105795b3fae3303074_1558519120.css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="b-combo">
      <div 
        class="b-combo__input 
        b-combo__input_multi_dropdown 
        b-combo__input_init_citiesList 
        b-combo__input_on_click_request_id_getcities 
        override_value_id_0_0_Все+страны 
        override_value_id_1_0_Все+города 
        combo__input_orientation_left "
      >
        <input class="b-combo__input-text" name="location" type="text" size="80" value="Все страны" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
    </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://st.fl.ru/wdstatic/d4df244d6b03270e5411b22ce566cf42_1558519120.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://st.fl.ru/wdstatic/c10e6af9fade16684be48dd6d918f72a_1499545529.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: это помогает сделать момент загрузки независимым от загрузки содержимого самой страницы.Но это не то. нужно что-то, что ограничит действие кода. чтоб он не влиял на весь остальной

Answer (score 0):

После подключения jQuery

```
var myJq = $.noConflict(true);
```

и в своём коде пользоваться им.